# Lorentz Transformation of massive Spin-1 fields

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-spin, field-theory, representation-theory, poincare-symmetry

First, let me give a summary of the relevant background:
In the QFT book by Schwartz, in Chapter 8.2.2, we derive a Lagrangian for a massive Spin-1 field:
$$
\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2} A_{\mu} \square A_{\mu}-\frac{1}{2} A_{\mu} \partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu} A_{\nu}+\frac{1}{2} m^{2} A_{\mu}^{2}\tag{8.23}
$$
The Lagrangian was constructed such, that $A_{\mu}$ has to transform like a 4-vector under Lorentz transformations, in order for the Lagrangian to be Lorentz-invariant.

Now, an arbitrary solution of the equations of motion can be written as
$$
A_{\mu}(x)=\sum_{i} \int \frac{d^{3} \vec{p}}{(2 \pi)^{3}} \bar{a}_{i}(\vec{p}) \epsilon_{\mu}^{i}(p) e^{i p x}, \quad p_{0}=\omega_{p}=\sqrt{\vec{p}^{2}+m^{2}},\tag{8.28}
$$
where, for each $p$ we have three independent polarization vectors $\epsilon_{\mu}^{i}(p)$. All these polarization vectors together then span a vector space of infinite dimension, where each point in the vector space (specified by the $\bar{a}_{i}(\vec{p})$) gives a solution $A_{\mu}(x)$.

Schwartz then states:

> The vector space generated by integrating these basis
> vectors against arbitrary Fourier components $\bar{a}_{i}(\vec{p})$ in Eq. (8.28) is the space of fields satisfying the equations of motion, which form an infinite-dimensional unitary representation
> of the Poincare group

My question is now: How does the Lorentz group (or the Poincare group) act on this vector space (spanned by the polarizations $\epsilon_{\mu}^{i}(p)$) such, that $A_{\mu}(x)$ still transforms like a 4-vector and how do we know, that this representation is unitary?